# My pizza dough is too dense

Tags: pizza

Followed two different pizza dough recipes before even getting to letting them rose I know something was wrong. Felt like too dry, dense and not at all sticky. We used bread flour. Warmed the water for the active dry yeast. The dough rose but still is too dense to spread and does not pass the “window pane test” Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include the recipe and / or a photo?

Comment: Also, what sort of pizza are you making (crust thickness in particular) and what temperature do you intend to bake it at?

Comment: how much water and flour did the recipe call for?  It sounds like it was too dry… which is very tricky to fix after the fact, as you end up just slicking down the outside of the doughball